# The method neo4jServer in the file DatabaseConfiguration.java of type DatabaseConfiguration must override or implement a supertype."

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want to develop a java application on top of a Neo4j graph database.
For this application I want to reuse the boiler plate code from Mr. Vlastaridis on Github via https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-neo4j-app/tree/2a6fa89f8c8aa13dc7ea7856b4ee521efceeb7c7

This Neo4j example is developed for the old 2.xx version of Neo4j. I want to update the database to version 3.xx. Therefore I have to update the Spring Data Neo4j project implementation in this application.

I have therefore modified the necessary entries in the POM.XML file. I used the properties and dependencies of https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4 as an example for the modifications in my POM.XML file. 
To my knowledge this top POM.XML implementation should result using Spring Boot into an inclusion of all other dependancies including the necessary Spring Data Neo4j dependencies. This seems not to be the case however.
As a result of the modified POM.XML I end up with an error in Eclipse and Maven: "The method neo4jServer in the file DatabaseConfiguration.java of type DatabaseConfiguration must override or implement a supertype."

Question: how do I modify the POM.XML in the boiler plate code in order to remove the error message?

The implementation of DatabaseConfiguration.java looks like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.config;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import  org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy;


@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.myapp.repository", queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

@Override
@Bean
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    log.info("Initialising server connection");
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474", "neo4j", "1234");
}

@Override
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    log.info("Initialising Session Factory");
    return new SessionFactory("com.mycompany.myapp.domain");
}

@Override
@Bean
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    log.info("Initialising session-scoped Session Bean");
    return super.getSession();
}
```

}

My POM.XML file looked like this. Due to the limitations of Stackoverflow I removed most of the non-Neo4j related properties and dependencies in this POM.XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4jhipster</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>neo4jhipster</name>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <hikaricp.version>2.4.1</hikaricp.version>
    <assertj-core.version>3.1.0</assertj-core.version>
    <awaitility.version>1.4.0</awaitility.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <gatling.version>2.1.7</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>2.1.7</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.0.0.CR1</mapstruct.version>
       <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
    <maven-sortpom-plugin.version>2.3.0</maven-sortpom-plugin.version>
    <metrics-spark-reporter.version>1.2</metrics-spark-reporter.version>
    <metrics-spring.version>3.1.2</metrics-spring.version>
    <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <springfox.version>2.0.3</springfox.version>
    <!-- Sonar properties -->
    <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>2.6</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/assets/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/dist/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/karma</sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>
    <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
    <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    <sonar.tests>${project.basedir}/src/test/</sonar.tests>


    <neo4j.version>3.0.1</neo4j.version>
    <neo4j-ogm.version>1.1.4</neo4j-ogm.version>
    <!-- sdn.version veranderd door Luc van 4.0.0.RELEASE naar 4.1.1.RELEASE -->
    <sdn.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</sdn.version>
    <!--  Einde verandering Luc -->
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Hopper-SR1</spring-data-releasetrain.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency -->
    <!-- spring-data-neo4j -->
     <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${sdn.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test scoped beans only -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${sdn.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-sortpom-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sort</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
                <nrOfIndentSpace>4</nrOfIndentSpace>
                <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFolder>src/test/gatling/conf</configFolder>
                <dataFolder>src/test/gatling/data</dataFolder>
                <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                <bodiesFolder>src/test/gatling/bodies</bodiesFolder>
                <simulationsFolder>src/test/gatling/simulations</simulationsFolder>
                <!-- This will force Gatling to ask which simulation to run
                  This is useful when you have multiple simulations -->
                <simulationClass>*</simulationClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven plugin toevoeging Luc 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        Einde Maven plugin toevoeging Luc -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireMavenVersion>
                        <message>You are running an older version of Maven. JHipster requires at least Maven 3.0</message>
                        <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                    </requireMavenVersion>
                    <requireJavaVersion>
                        <message>You are running an older version of Java. JHipster requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                        <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                    </requireJavaVersion>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m ${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after unit tests have been run -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOutputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                </defaultOutputDirectory>
                <processors>
                    <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                </processors>
                <options>
                    <mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>true</mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>
                    <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>spring</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
                </options>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-plugin -->
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--
                This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only.
                It has no influence on the Maven build itself.
                Remove when the m2e plugin can correctly bind to Maven lifecycle
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jacoco-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.7.4,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- log configuration -->
            <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>fast</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- log configuration -->
            <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>true</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev,fast</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
                    <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-frontend-build</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <buildTool>grunt</buildTool>
                                <buildArgs>build --force --no-color</buildArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <yeomanProjectDirectory>${project.basedir}</yeomanProjectDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/dist</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>.tmp</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>node_modules</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- this is set to false because of https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2225 -->
                        <executable>false</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <!-- log configuration -->
            <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using spring-data-neo4j in version 4.1.1.RELEASE. In your `DatabaseConfiguration` class you are extending `Neo4jConfiguration`. Your problem is, like the error says, you want to override a method which is not existing in the superclass. In version 4.1.1.RELEASE of SDN there is no method called `neo4jServer` what you can override (This method was removed something about 4.1.0.RELEASE)

So what you can do is to change your configuration suitable on the SDN version you are using - remove the `neo4jServer` method and use a configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.mycompany.myapp");
}

@Bean
public Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(getSession());
}

@Bean
public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();

    config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
            .setURI("http://localhost:7474")
            .setCredentials("neo4j", "1234");

    return config;
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
}
```

Another option (what i would not recommend) is to change the version of SDN in your pom.xml to

```
<spring-data-neo4j.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
```